# Redirect in-memory class log to ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, class, client-server, objectoutputstream, in-memory

I'm trying to build a client-server IDE, and I'm having problems with getting the error log/exception log of runtime exceptions from the in-memory compiled/run class.

My code looks like this:

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
private ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
private PrintStream out;

public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
    try {
        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out = new PrintStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        StringBuffer sourceCode = new StringBuffer();
        sourceCode.append(objectInputStream.readObject());

        Class<?> myClass = MyJavaCompiler.compile("Test", sourceCode.toString());
        Method mainMethod = myClass != null ? myClass.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class) : null;
        Object myObject = myClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
        try {
            System.setOut(out);
            System.out.print(mainMethod.invoke(myObject, new Object[]{null}));
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Class<?>[] exceptionsList = mainMethod.getExceptionTypes();
            for(Class<?> c : exceptionsList){
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(c.getName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

and this is the compiler:

```
import javax.tools.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by alin on 8/23/15.
 */
public class MyJavaCompiler {

private static JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

public static Class<?> compile(String className, String sourceCodeInText) throws Exception {

    JavaSourceFromString sourceCode = new JavaSourceFromString(className, sourceCodeInText);

    CompiledCode compiledCode = new CompiledCode(className);
    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(sourceCode);
    DynamicClassLoader dynamicClassLoader = new DynamicClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    MyJavaFileManager fileManager = new MyJavaFileManager(javac.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null), compiledCode, dynamicClassLoader);

    JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = javac.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits);
    boolean result = task.call();
    if(result){
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        return dynamicClassLoader.loadClass(className);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("FAIL");
        return null;
        }
    }
}
```

At this moment, when I have, for example NullPointerException in my in-memory class, I get "[]" sent to client.

EDIT:

Thanks Holger for your answer and feedback. I managed to get the code to do what i wanted by simply adding e.printStackTrace(PrintStream), code below:

```
try {
            System.setOut(out);
            System.out.print(mainMethod.invoke(myObject, new Object[]{null}));
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(out);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
        }
```

The idea was to redirect my error output from my in-memory class to client from server.

Answer (score 0):

You should get used to a consistent behavior regarding `null` treatment. Here

```
Class<?> myClass = MyJavaCompiler.compile("Test", sourceCode.toString());
Method mainMethod = myClass != null ? myClass.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class) : null;
Object myObject = myClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

You are considering that `myClass` could be `null` when initializing `mainMethod` but right in the next line you are unconditionally invoking `getConstructor()` on `myClass` which would lead to a `NullPointerException` when `myClass` is `null`. Even when that didn’t fail, you have assigned `null` to `mainMethod` in case `myClass` is `null`, but are going to call `invoke`, again without checking for `null`.

Nevertheless, when your `compile` method returns a non-`null` value, you will proceed, but in the case you receive an `InvocationTargetException`, you are not going to send anything related to that exception, in fact you are not accessing `e` at all, but instead you are sending the result of `mainMethod.getExceptionTypes()` which are the types which that method *declares* via `throws` clause. That list might indeed be empty, the `main` method doesn’t need to declare any exceptions and may still throw `RuntimeException`s  or `Error`s.

You are also performing `myClass.getConstructor().newInstance();` *outside* that `try … catch` clause and any throwable thrown by this constructor will get handled by the outer `try … catch` in the worst way ever possible, `catch (Exception e) {}` …